# plupload filename to database problems

Tags: plupload, sql-insert

I have troubles trying to save the file name of an uploaded file with Plupload. Here is the Plupload section:

```
echo<<<_END
  <div id="container">
    <div id="filelist">No runtime found.</div>
    <br />
    <a id="pickfiles" href="javascript:;">[Select file]</a> 
    <a id="uploadfiles" href="javascript:;">[Upload it]</a>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  // Custom example logic
    function $(id) {
      return document.getElementById(id);
    }

  var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,browserplus',browse_button : 'pickfiles',container: 'container',max_file_size : '1mb',
    url : 'upload.php',
    resize : {width : 320, height : 240, quality : 90},
    flash_swf_url : 'plupload/js/plupload.flash.swf',
    silverlight_xap_url : 'plupload/js/plupload.silverlight.xap',
    filters : [{title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,jpeg,gif,png"}]
  });

  uploader.bind('Init', function(up, params) {
    $('filelist').innerHTML = "<div>Current runtime: " + params.runtime + "</div>"; 
  });

  uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
    for (var i in files) {
      $('filelist').innerHTML += '<div id="' + files[i].id + '">' + files[i].name     + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(files[i].size) + ') <b></b></div>';
    }});

  uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function(up, file) {
    $(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%    </span>";
  });

  $('uploadfiles').onclick = function() {
    uploader.start();
    return false;
  };

  uploader.init();
</script>
_END;
```

But I have no idea how to insert the file name into my database:

```
$post_img = file??

$topicid = mysql_insert_id();
$sql = "INSERT INTO
    posts(post_content,
    post_date,
    post_topic,
    post_by,
    post_img
  )
  VALUES
  (
    '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post_content']) . "',
    NOW(),
    " . $topicid . ",
    " . $_SESSION['userid'] . ",
    " . $post_img . " )";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);

  if(!$result) {
    //something went wrong, display the error
    echo 'An error occured while inserting your post. Please try again later.<br /><br />' . mysql_error();
    $sql = "ROLLBACK;";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
  }
```

I am getting the error 'An error occured while inserting your post. Please try again later'

Comment: what mysql_error() or mysql_errno() return?

Comment: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1. I changed the value to $_FILES['$fileName'], but still the same problem. Thanks

Comment: but anyway, if I take out post_img from the Insert Into, make a variable $post_img = $_FILES['$fileName']; and echo $post_img later, it doesn't give any output :-/

Comment: first, why $topicid = mysql_insert_id(); there? then did you move $_FILES['tmp_name'] to a different folder giving it a name?

Comment: Mr Book Of Zeus, there are two queries to save the data- one for topics (basically it is the title, category and amount of comments) and other for the actual post (the one shown here). On the other hand, I'm very new with JavaScript and I'm not sure what you mean with moving $_FILES['tmp_name']. Should I set  $_FILES['images/']?

Comment: Things that I forgot to tell: the files upload fine and in the place where I want them to! But the problem is that I don't know how to get the file name so I can throw it to the database. Trying to put the value of $_SESSION['fileName'] for the field post_img gives me this error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.

Comment: Do you use: move_uploaded_file?

Comment: nope, why do you think I should?

Comment: read: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: I was kind of exited when I started reading the move_uploaded_file manual but it didn't work :-/ I went with the example they give but the browser encounters an error in the first foreach. So I erased it and just went with $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key]; $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key]; move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name"); but getting to the same place :-( When I print_r($_FILES); I get Array (). Always an empty array! I has to do with the files[i].id since I see the uploaded file after uploaded 100% in both the output and in the folder it uploaded.

Comment: well if $_FILES return an empty array, maybe you don't use the right thing in the form: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: I gave up :-/ I just direct to a new page to upload a file and update the db from there. I want to take these few more lines to THANK YOU for your time, for answering all questions and teaching me. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

I put the mysql query into the `upload.php` file. 
I'm not really sure where in that file to put it, but I guess its in the "Check if file has been uploaded" part, at the end of the `upload.php` file.

```
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {

// Strip the temp .part suffix off 
rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);

    //your mysql query here**************************
}
```

The reason why I think it could be here, is because it checks if there are any chunks left from the uploaded file. If its not any left, you are inside the `if` statement. The `upload.php` runs `foreach` over every uploaded file, so you simply put `$fileName` into the database.

It works for me. Hope it helps